# ansible chdir module not working on remote server?

Tags: ansible

I am using a ansible playbook and it is running fine on my local system but when I run the same playbook on a remote server then it fails due to a error given by chdir module **i.e** `"msg": [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, `"rc": 2`.

Please if anyone can help me figure out what is the exact issue here.

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    test: "Test Successfull"
    repo_dir: /media/disk1/sandbox/xyz
    path: /media/disk1/sandbox/xyz/api
  tasks:
   - debug:
         msg: "{{ test.split()[0] }} {{ test.split()[1] }}"

   - name: Running npm install in directory "{{ path }} and {{ repo_dir }}/lib as well"
     command: npm install
     args:
         chdir: "{{ item }}"
     loop:
         - "{{ path }}"
         - "{{ repo_dir }}/lib"
     become_user: yash
     become: yes
```

Comment: Are you sure the repo_dir and path exists in the remote server?

Comment: yes it exists, i found out that when i remove npm install from the command then chdir works fine. so issue is with that can u suggest me any other way to install my npm packages.

Comment: did you try with npm module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/npm_module.html

Comment: how will I give my package.json where all the packages to be installed are defined in it using this module.

Comment: are u there..??

Comment: @YashTandon: look at the list of params and the examples in the doc. This is done with the `path` parameter.

Comment: 'path' param specifies the directory where u want to install the module also i cant specify names of module as those are hundreds in number so i am using a package.json to install the modules.

Comment: Your above comment just proves you did not read the doc and the examples correctly, especially the one "name: Update packages based on package.json to their latest version."

Comment: you were right i completely missed that example, i used your approach but still facing issues, please have a look as i have shared a link for error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below.

```
- name: Running npm install
  npm:
    path:"{{ package_path }}"
    executable: "{{ npm_path }}"
```

where {{ package_path }} is path to package.json file and {{npm_path}} is /usr/bin/npm( as per your npm path)

Comment: Sir i tried your approach but it has given me a new error plz have a look, link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iaNMIjR3EVFYVvSoJEPTmjhSrDsnfZc5VCvUUamdKps/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: have updated the document and included the playbook.